# Element not inlined properly with padding:0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The button with text "Project Howto" is supposed to be inlined with the button with text "Sign In or Register"

I remove the padding `padding:0` already but when i inspect it.. padding still appears

```
<div class="btn-group input-group-btn" style="padding:0;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="margin:0px;">
  Project HowTo:
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hjAGo

Comment: I visited the link, the button is inline..what is the problem?

Comment: the buttons on the right must have the same height

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hjfnp no padding seems to appear check with this

Comment: How abt this `padding:0!important;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding musn't be removed on `<div> btn-group input-group-btn` but on child `<button> btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle`. Then, your padding is removed.

But it still won't be the same height because :

- The font size is different
- You have two elements in your second button

The only way to force these buttons to share the same height is to give them a specific one :

```
btn-group.input-group-btn button {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByIwl

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Project HowTo:` button has the padding, the button group is giving padding.

Set the following css to `btn btn-default dropdown-toggle` element:

```
  .input-group-btn:last-child>.btn {
  padding: 1.5px 4px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  }
```

You can give inline style or add a custom class for that element with the given style to override.

Answer (score 0):

#### I tried this, and it worked. Added inline style for padding 0.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="margin:0px;padding:0;">
              Project HowTo:
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
```